# Spotfire: Multiple Average Lines on Bar Chart

Tags: average, bar-chart, spotfire, trendline

How do I add an average line for each of the columns in my bar chart in Spotfire seperately?

The image below shows a green, blue, and red column that I would like to obtain the average of individually and then plot each on the chart.
[image]

Comment: Please provide a live demo like http://jsfiddle.net and we will see.

Comment: Average of each column or group of columns (one pink / green/blue) ?

Comment: Average of each group of column, so one pink line, one green line, one blue line. So a total of 3 lines on the chart. I have adjusted the image to show this

Comment: I'm confused - is this a spotfire question or a highcharts question?

Comment: Spotfire. Removed highcharts tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on each serie and then sum all points from serie, divide by amout of points and then add line by [addPlotLine](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine).

```
    var yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

    $.each(chart.series, function(i,serie){
        var average = 0;
        $.each(serie.data, function(j, data){
            average += data.y;
        });
        yAxis.addPlotLine({
            value: (average / serie.data.length),
            color: serie.color,
            width:1
        });

    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a04x74zc/